# my.classpath.Servletname was found, but is corrupted: SRVE0227E:

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I have received the following error when trying to deploy a servlet to bluemix:

> SRVE0227E: Check that the class resides in the proper package
>   directory. SRVE0228E: Check that the classname has been defined in the
>   server using the proper case and fully qualified package. SRVE0229E:
>   Check that the class was transferred to the filesystem using a binary
>   transfer mode. SRVE0230E: Check that the class was compiled using the
>   proper case (as defined in the class definition). SRVE0231E: Check
>   that the class file was not renamed after it was compiled.*

I have checked the servlet as per the error message, but could not find the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was simply because I was compiling my web application using a 1.8 JDK when I should have been using a 1.7 JDK.  As soon as I swapped the JDK, the problem was fixed.

The error message threw me because it was very specific, but didn't mention anything about class versions.

Comment: Was the actual (cause) exception that was thrown by the classloader in the stacktrace?

Comment: I can't remember seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with  java version,which you already sorted out.\

Just incase some one needs more details on this error,can follow below link:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/359899/Servlets/java/Servlet-corrupt-message